# HDFS to HDFS move files force fully

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera

As per my knowledge, there is no straight option to overwrite the file in HDFS while doing a move from one HDFS location to other, copying `cp` has the option to force. I'm trying to find if there is any hack to do that?

what we can do is `hdfs dfs -cp -f /hdfs/location1 /hdfs/location2` but not `hdfs dfs -mv -f /hdfs/location1/ /hdfs/location2/`

One way to achieve my purpose is to do the `hdfs dfs -cp -f /hdfs/location1 /hdfs/location2` first and then get rid of the location1 file with `hdfs dfs -rm -r /hdfs/location1` but I don't want to do that for some reason. Any other approach with one single command will be appriciated.

thanks in advance !!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: This question is related to Hadoop, can I still ask in Super User and Unix & Linux Stack Exchange?  Thanks

Comment: FYI... `hdfs dfs -cp -f` isn't doing it atomically either... Internally it's calling delete followed by a copy. So... it's not really any better than a two command solution.

Comment: Did you ever find a 'force' solution to for `hdfs dfs -mv`?

Comment: @Petro I haven't found the solution yet, living with workaround for now.

Answer (score 0):

Not a single command and rather a workaround:

For merging folders in HDFS I implemented a solution for this, since cp interacts with the physical data on the data nodes whereas mv only changes metadata on the name node.

```
for i in $(hdfs dfs -ls -R ${hdfs_src_dir} | grep "^-" | awk '{print $8}'); do
  i_dir=$(dirname "${i}")
  target_dir=${hdfs_tgt_dir}${i_dir#"$hdfs_src_dir"}
  hdfs dfs -mkdir -p $target_dir
  hdfs dfs -mv ${i} "${target_dir}"/ 2>&1
done
```

The first line selects all files in a destination recursively. The paths of each file in the target are then created and the files finally moved.

A downside is that the folder access rights are not moved but rather set at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

HDFS shell commands doesn't support a `-f` for `mv`.

You will have to do the copy then remove method (as stated by you).

Answer (score -4):

There is no way of doing this in a single command something like

hdfs dfs -rm {destination Uri} ; hdfs dfs -mv {source Uri} {destination Uri}

Would achieve this on a single line.

Comment: Thanks, but that’s the same thing removing and moving. I mentioned one command in the different sense.

Comment: Ok thanks, NIFI has been useful for this, but still it's annoying